# Can C# do everything C++ can do?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, memory

I'm a C# programmer for a few months, and lately I've been considering learning C++.

So my question is, is there anything C++ can do that C# can't do?

I know about the manual memory management in C++, but as long as I don't program operating systems or extremely heavy memory applications, I shouldn't worry about that too much (becuase I heard .NET handles automatic memory management very well).

But, can I program in C# everything that I can in C#? I also mean things like DLL injection, Registry Editing, Drivers and things like that.

Is C# considered as powerful as C++? If not, what can't C# do that C++ can?

Comment: Template metaprogramming.

Comment: Programming embedded devices (no C# runtime).

Comment: From the theoretical point of view, the class of algorithms you can define is the same.

Comment: You can't write directly to hardware, since you can't "bypass" the memory handling. But then again, most people never have a need for this in "normal" programming, since it belongs in the "operating systems" category. Having said that, what's wrong with learning another language. It absolutely can't hurt. And then you can sit in an interview with a prospective employer and explain exactly the questions you just asked, should you happen to get that sort of question. Never hurts to know more.

Comment: Can you clarify which language you *did* learn and which you *want* to learn? Your question gives conflicting information in that regard.

Comment: Both are powerful in their way. C# can do sooo many things, you simply can't do (or with a lot of work9 which c++ can't do. But there are also so many things c++ can do which c# can't do.

Comment: _"can I program in C# everything that I can in C#?"_ - confusing names, eh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# and C++ are languages. It's somewhat elusive to define what a language "can" and "can't" do. <s>One example of a thing that C++ can do and C# can't, is free the memory of an heap allocated object at will, without freeing other unused objects as well. But it's a thing that won't matter most of the time.</s> (You can use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` to allocate and deallocate memory like in C.)

The main reason why C++ can be used to write things like Windows drivers is because this is what Windows supports and facilitates. If one day Microsoft decided to support only C# and ditch C++, we'd be here saying that C# can do something that C++ can't (even if the languages magically remained as they are now, by then). Most likely it won't, and rightly so, because C++ is better fit for systems programming than C#. But hopefully you get the point.

Essentially, it's not a matter of the languages themselves, but their implementations, their tools and the world around them. For example, [you can easily write an operating system in C#](https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos). Why? Because there's a proper tool for it. [You can also write for embedded systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) with non-real-time requirements. It has nothing to do with the language, again, it's because there's a tool for it.

That being said, do learn C++. Regardless of how it compares with other languages, it's absolutely useful.

Answer (score 5):

C# is a slightly higher level language that C++. Its requirement of a managed runtime environment means that you wont be able to write an operating system, or even a device driver, in it. This sort of area is typically known as systems programming

However, there is a Microsoft research project currently underway into creating a systems program version of C#. It's headed up by Joe Duffy, the Windows threading guru, and if the rumors on the web are to be believed it will be called **M#**. Joe has posted some information about his progress on his [blog](http://joeduffyblog.com/2013/12/27/csharp-for-systems-programming/).

Comment: See [C# Open Source Managed Operating System](http://cosmos.codeplex.com/)

Comment: OK, And if we ignore Operating Systems and Drivers, can C++ do stuff that C# can't (ignoring Operating Systems)? I mean, for example, in the 3D games category. Can every 3D game written in C++ be written in C#, and run at similar speeds, for example?

Comment: @BlueRay010 - sure, you can write plenty of 3D games in C#. I suspect a large majority of the games in the Window 8 store are written this way, and they're probably comparable to a C++ equivalent. However, I don't thing you'll be seeing a Crysis port to C# in a hurry!